# want to copy modified column data + unmodified data from one sheet to other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy

The following code copies only the last value of the column from "firstsheet" to the one   the new sheet"secondsheet". Can someone help me to copy the column from sheet "firstsheet" to "secondsheet" with the matching condition which is RGB(255,255, 0).

```
Sub CopyColumns()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
      //  Set ws = Worksheets("secondsheet")

     For Each c2 In Worksheets("secondsheet").Range("B4:B80").Cells
        For Each c In Worksheets("firstsheet").Range("C3:C79").Cells
            If c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            c2.Value = c.Value
            c2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
            End If
        Next c
     Next c2





    End Sub
```

Comment: why not just copy the entire range (it is not that big) and then delete the cells (shift:=xlUp) which do not match the desired criteria?

Comment: well yeah, but the data gets bigger. I am working just on a template with smaller data. And later I believe, the values in the "firstsheet" will change. So i need to automate things so I wouldn't have problem later on.

Comment: OK, then we're going to need more information about what you're actually trying to achieve here. You are doing a nested iteration which is probably not what you want -- right now for each cell in `secondSheet` you're comparing *every single cell in the range on `firstsheet` against each `c2`. So it makes sense that the `c2` is not updating as you might expect.

Comment: my vote is a filter, copy, paste special solution.  Are you overwriting the data on "secondsheet" each time you run the macro?

Comment: yeah. I think so i was comparing two of them. I am trying to copy  the data from firstsheet to secondsheet that matches the requirement. Basically I want to copy all data from the column but in the new sheet with the different color for the one that matches + unmodified.

Comment: @sous2817 yes I am overwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my stab at is is below.  A couple of things...You don't need to loop, let the built in functionality do the heavy lifting.  This also assumes that B3 on "firstsheet" is a header and you want the data to go in C4 of "secondsheet".  My guess is you'll have to adjust the ranges a bit to suit.  This also will handle data as the structure changes (gets bigger).  It also assumes you're using Excel2007 or greater:

```
Sub test()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("secondsheet")
    lastRow = Application.Max(4, .Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("C4:C" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With

With Sheets("firstsheet")
    lastRow = .Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B3:B" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    .Range("B4:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("secondsheet").Range("C4")
    .Range("B3:B" & lastRow).AutoFilter
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. Just would like to have have all data copy that doesnt match criteria and change the color that matches the criteria

Comment: @apariyar I'm a bit confused.  After it's copied, you want it to have a color of RGB(255, 0, 255)?

Comment: Yes  i want the color changed.

Comment: You can add this beween the first .AutoFilter and .SpecialCells lines: .Range("B4:B" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)

Comment: Thank you very much sous2817. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @apariyar you're quite welcome and good luck with the rest of your project!